# Trying to add constraints of the UIImageView array

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I created the array of the UIImageViews, and stored 5 image views inside, with no constraints.

```
lazy var albumImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImage(named: "authorizationImage")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.backgroundColor = .black
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}()

lazy var albumImages: [UIImageView] = [albumImage, albumImage, albumImage, albumImage, albumImage]
```

I added them to my UIView:

```
for row in 0...(albumImages.count-1){
    backView.addSubview(albumImages[row])
}
```

And tried to set up the constraints of each based on the UILabel, which I have on top of my UIView:

```
for row in 0...(albumImages.count-1){
    let distanceFromTop = ((row*30) + (row+1)*10)
    print("geez \(row) distance \(distanceFromTop)")
    albumImages[row].topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: registrationTime.bottomAnchor, constant: CGFloat(distanceFromTop)).isActive = true
    albumImages[row].leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    albumImages[row].rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumImages[row].leftAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
    albumImages[row].heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}
```

I can see the first UIImageView on my simulator. However, other 4 are not shown. I got the error message in my console saying:

```
geez 0 distance 10
geez 1 distance 50
2020-08-12 17:16:38.174252+0900 WhosFan[24100:2336027] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000167cbe0 V:[UILabel:0x7f97ae8603b0'Based on (KST) : 2020.08....']-(10)-[UIImageView:0x7f97aeb20d60]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000016777f0 V:[UILabel:0x7f97ae8603b0'Based on (KST) : 2020.08....']-(50)-[UIImageView:0x7f97aeb20d60]   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000016777f0 V:[UILabel:0x7f97ae8603b0'Based on (KST) : 2020.08....']-(50)-[UIImageView:0x7f97aeb20d60]   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I checked if I added subviews in wrong order. However, everything looks fine:

```
 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    addSubview(backView)
    backView.addSubview(cellTitle)
    backView.addSubview(registrationTime)
    addAlbumImages()
    setupConstraints()
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
private func setupConstraints(){
    setUpCellTitleConstraints()
    setUpRegistrationDateLabelConstraints()
    setupAlbumImagesConstraints()
}
```

I was stacked in this problem for last 2 hours. Please, any help.
here is the image of my simulator:

[image]

Comment: you are having same instance in the array ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating *one* image view here (not 5!) and adding that same image view to the array 5 times:

```
lazy var albumImages: [UIImageView] = [albumImage, albumImage, albumImage, albumImage, albumImage]
```

This is why all your constraints broke, and only one image view is shown. There is only one image view, and that image view's top anchor needs to simultaneously be 10, 50, 90, 130, and 170 points away from `registrationTime.bottomAnchor`!

Anyway, you should create a new image view each time when adding them to the array. One way to do this is to make `albumImage` into a method, `createAlbumImageView`:

```
func createAlbumImageView() -> UIImageView {
    let image = UIImage(named: "authorizationImage")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    imageView.backgroundColor = .black
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return imageView
}
```

And then the array can be declared like so:

```
lazy var albumImages: [UIImageView] = [
    createAlbumImageView(),
    createAlbumImageView(),
    createAlbumImageView(),
    createAlbumImageView(),
    createAlbumImageView(),
]
```

---

It seems like your image views are in a vertical line, with *somewhat* equal spacing. I'm not sure whether the unequal spacing is simply caused by another mistake. If equal spacing is desired, you could instead use a vertical [`UIStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uistackview).

Comment: Thank you! I am new in iOS development, so did not even think that I am setting up the constraints of the same UIImageView! Thank you! I changed it to the function, which returns the new UIIMageView, and it works just fine!